# Get newly added value in Array Powershell

Tags: powershell, contains, equality

```
for (;;) {

  #Get All Files from the Folder
    
  $FolderItems = @(Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderURL -ItemType File)
    
  Write-Host "Total Number of Files in the Folder:" $FolderItems.Count
  if ($FolderItems.Count -gt $oldCount) {
    foreach ($item in $FolderItems) {
      if ($oldFolderItems -contains $item) {                
      }
      else {
        Write-Host $item.Name
      }
            
    } 
  }
  $oldCount = $FolderItems.Count    
  $oldFolderItems = $FolderItems
    
  timeout 180   

}
```

It prints all the names instead of the one new item

Comment: Change `write-host $item` to `write-host $item.Name` if you want it to print the name. Your caching logic won't work though, variables in PowerShell are scoped to where ever they are being assigned, so `$oldFolderItems` will stop existing as soon as the function finishes/returns

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That defeats the purpose..so how do I check the new file list against the old one? Move both arrays out of the fucntion then? old and new one?

Comment: You could return the file count from within your function with `Write-Host $FolderItems.Count` and the file array with `Write-Output $FolderItems`. Then when you run your function, something like `$output = fileOps`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I took care of all that, now my If loop is not working. Updated the code.

Comment: Took me 4 hours to figure out `$oldFolderItems` was not an array.

Comment: Well, `$oldFolderItems` _is_ an array, due to use of `@(...)`

Comment: @mklement0 that was my assumption too. However it was only when I added another `foreach` loop to add each item again in the `$oldFolderItems`  only then it started behaving like an `array`

Comment: @mklement0 This is my first script in powershell..so I also don't understand for sure. Your explanation cleared things up for me though. Thanks a lot for your time and guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Replace your `foreach` loop with the following call to [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object):

```sh
# Compare the new and the old collection items by their .Name property
# and output the name of those that are unique to the new collection.
Compare-Object -Property Name $FolderItems $oldFolderItems |
  Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<=' |
    ForEach-Object Name
```

You should also initialize `$oldFolderItems`  to `$null` and `$oldCount` to `0`, to be safe, and - unless you want *all* names to be output in the first iteration - change the enclosing `if` statement to:
`if ($oldFolderItems -and $FolderItems.Count -gt $oldCount) { # ...`

Note: The **immediate - but inefficient - fix** to your attempt would have been the following, for the reasons explained in the next section:

```sh
if ($oldFolderItems.Name -contains $item.Name) { # Compare by .Name values
```

<sup>Note: `$oldFolderItems.Name` actually returns the *array* of `.Name` property values of the *elements* in collection `$oldFolderItems`, which is a convenient feature named [*member-access enumeration*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration).</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

It's unclear what .NET type `Get-PnPFolderItem` returns instances of, but it's fair to assume that the type is a .NET [*reference type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) (as opposed to a [*value type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)).

Unless a reference type is explicitly designed to compare its instances based on identifying properties,<sup>[1]</sup> ***reference equality* is tested for** in equality test-based operations such as [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) (but also in other equality-comparison operations, such as with `-in` and `-eq`), i.e. **only two references to the *very same instance* are considered equal**.

Therefore, using `-contains` in your case won't work, because the elements of the collections - even if they *conceptually* represent the same objects - are *distinct instances* that compare as *unequal*.

A simplified example, using [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances, as output by `Get-Item`:

```sh
# !! Returns $false, because the two [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
# !! instances are distinct objects.
@(Get-Item /) -contains (Get-Item /)
```

Therefore, **instances of .NET reference types must be compared by the *value of an identifying property* (if available, such as `.Name` in this case) rather than *as a whole*.**

To **discover whether a given instance is one of a .NET reference type**, access the type's `.IsValueType` property: a return value of `$false` indicates a reference type; e.g.:

```sh
(Get-Item /).GetType().IsValueType # -> $false -> reference type

# Equivalent, with a type literal
[System.IO.DirectoryInfo].IsValueType # -> $false
```

---

<sup>[1] A notable example is the `[string]` type, which, as an exception, generally behaves like a *value type*, so that the following is still `$true`, despite technically distinct instances being involved: `$s1 = 'foo'; $s2 = 'f' + 'oo'; $s1 -eq $s2`</sup>